# Error Uninstalling Our Managed Package - ManagedContentFolderDefinition

Tags: managed-package, metadata

Had a Support case open for 2 weeks now moving too slowly. Support pointed me to Dashboards and Reports as problem but that's a similar but different error and object. When trying to uninstall our own managed package getting:

**Error**

> This installed component is referenced by a locally created component.
> ManagedContentFolderDefinition.

That object is not listed in [MetaData Coverage Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/53). Only reference I can find is [blog](https://ehrenfest.com/post-2330/) by someone pointing to Experience Cloud CMS Content as the culprit; however we've tried removing all we can find and no success.

Are you familiar with object and if so how can we query something to find out where the issue is?